# calculating text sizing for dynamic content generation

Tags: ruby, prawn, dynamic-reports

I'm using Prawn to develop a PDF generator based on content that changes on a weekly basis, and need a way of automatically determining text sizing.

If it were a block of text, I would use the :shrink_to_fit method provided, however, the text formatting is not conducive to that as it consists of a variable amount of "stories", each of variable length, and each needs to start on a new line.

For example the stories may look like this:

```
Story one - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

Story two - text text text text text text text text text text.

Story three - longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text.
```

(and each story will automatically wrap to a new line)

The format of the data is ["Story one - text text etc", "Story two - text text etc", etc], so I'm creating the content by looping through the array and drawing text for each value

What is a good way of calculating font size in points? The height of the box is 130 points.